# Redirections the right way inside a plugin directory

Tags: plugin-development, redirect

I have a plugin, with the stylesheet:

/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/pluginName/templates/templateName/style.css

I'd like to access:
/wordpress/pluginName/templateName/style.css

I know I could change the .htaccess in order to do the redirects, but that wouldn't work on non-Apache servers. I could create a general re-direction code called:
core.php?t=templateName&f=style.css
and then the stylesheet in the template, all of the files, will be called from that specific file.

I prefer not to do that.
Which ways would you recommend to do that?

If I am going the .htaccess way, how can I manage the plugin install/uninstall, and other software re-writing the .htaccess? Does Wordpress manage that somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there any particular reason why you need to do this? you can accomplish it the same way WordPress achieves pretty permalinks, but considering WordPress runs just fine in setups where URL rewriting is not available, you have to accommodate that case anyway.

Comment: Use "template inculde" filter.